# Trying to read # in url??

Tags: java, jsp, url

question....this is coming back as false:

```
 <c:when test="${param.code != null && param.code != ''}">name="update"</c:when>
```

when this is in the url

http://localhost:8080/msst/dispatch/show.whatif_edit_rqmt_type?code=#

but it comes back as true when
http://localhost:8080/msst/dispatch/show.whatif_edit_rqmt_type?code=!

Is there something special about '#'??

thanks

Comment: is there a way to read the '#'?

Comment: No,  not on server-side. Only on client-side.

Comment: @user, your specific problem isn't reading the URL, it's that the URL is malformed. The URL in your example does not have a query parameter named "code" with a value of "#". It has a query parameter named "code" with no value. Where did you get the URL from? (The hash is a reserved character in URLs (to put it simply) and needs to be escaped, which hasn't happened here.)

Comment: @cularis, I think you're missing the context here. :)

Comment: @bzlm, yes, sorry :) but he can read the `#` clientside! :D

Comment: @cularis, now you're thinking with portals! :)

Comment: http://localhost:8080/msst/dispatch/show.whatif_edit_rqmt_type?code=A     ..is able to be read just fine...im building it on a jsp page

Comment: ok...so it needs to be escaped....cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The # sign is the browser hash and is not being sent to the server (usually to reference anchors in an HTML document or for navigation through AJAX applications). If you actually want to send it to the server you have to [URL encode](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) it to `%23`:

```
http://localhost:8080/msst/dispatch/show.whatif_edit_rqmt_type?code=%23
```

Comment: ...and this should have happened already, which means what's broken isn't the JSP code, but rather the URL generation.

Comment: thanx I knew it was something

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where your `param` variable comes from, but in general, yes, # is a [very special character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) in URLs.

Don't use it if you don't have to and if you do use it, make sure you encode your url.

Comment: @bzlm I meant when you just pick one character to mean something special in your app. Although normally all your parameters should be urlencoded anyway, but when you're testing your application with handcrafted URLs, it's quite inconvenient.